# How to define and use customized handler using AWS PyTorch base image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I plan to use this AWS base image for Sagemaker inference
https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/pytorch/inference/docker/1.12/py3/cu116/Dockerfile.gpu
Based on github links:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_pytorch_serving_container/serving.py

```
HANDLER_SERVICE = handler_service.__file__


def _retry_if_error(exception):
    return isinstance(exception, CalledProcessError)


@retry(stop_max_delay=1000 * 30,
       retry_on_exception=_retry_if_error)
def _start_torchserve():
    # there's a race condition that causes the model server command to
    # sometimes fail with 'bad address'. more investigation needed
    # retry starting mms until it's ready
    torchserve.start_torchserve(handler_service=HANDLER_SERVICE)
```

It uses this default handler service:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_pytorch_serving_container/handler_service.py

DEFAULT_HANDLER_SERVICE = "sagemaker_pytorch_serving_container.handler_service"

I am wondering how to make torchserve.start_torchserve use customized handler_service?